# Lumen not working out of the box

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

Just installed Lumen framework.
hit the link http://localhost/lumen/public/ in my browser and got this following error, anyone got any idea about it?
Traced it back to the app.php file in bootstrap folder.

[image: lumen application.php error]

Comment: You might want to look at [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) for local development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your terminal in the root folder run the following command  `php artisan serve`.

Lumen development server started on http://localhost:8000/

Comment: @Ggmon could you please be more specific regarding what the issue is exactly?

Comment: There are one way to solve this. See this https://github.com/mlntn/lumen-artisan-serve

Answer (score 28):

if You want to access lumen project without "php artisan serve"

`$app->run();` replace with 
`$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);`
from this path  `yourlumenproject/public/index.php`

Comment: For me this is the best and simplest answer :)

Comment: I wish I'd found this an hour ago.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly!!

Comment: Had the same issue. Works for me as well. Can you explain in short why do we have to do this?

Comment: $app->run(); this was return default request of app but for run normally i made a capture request and after this when app will run it will not use default request

Answer (score 8):

if you want to serve your app in local development you can do this :

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

and it will serve in localhost in port 8000. hope this help.

Note : I'm using Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.2.4) (Laravel Components 5.2.*)

Answer (score 6):

At the moment Lumen only runs in the **domain root**.
*(I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/pull/35) that fixes this but it has yet to be merged)*

You have to create a *Virtual Host* on your local webserver and point the document root of that to the *public* directory. After that you can access your app with something like: `http://lumen.dev`.

- [Guide for Virtual Hosts with nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
- [Guide for Virtual Hosts with Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

A simple alternative to setting this up manually is [**Laravel Homestead**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead). It is an official Vagrant box made for Laravel, that allows you to easily get your development environment up and running.