# Why has the artisan serve command been removed from Lumen 5.2?

Tags: laravel-artisan, lumen, lumen-5.2

Please. Does anybody know why Lumen's team removed the command `php artisan serve`? That command was very helpful !.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29713635/1699210)

Comment: As Feeda and JamesG said, if you just want a simple way to serve your app, use the built-in php web server. I've implemented it in Lumen 5.3 here: https://gist.github.com/dotnetCarpenter/b0801d4e5e5688de390ed4c1d7342450

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't speak for Taylor, but my guess is that his reasoning is that a given microframework should not know - or care - about the server that's running it. A microframework should just assume that it's going to work, and leave it to the developer to figure out which tools are best to make that happen.

Laravel is different, in that it offers a more "complete" - and highly opinionated - set of tools to get your web application off the ground. In a full-stack framework, it's not uncommon to provide at least a simple PHP server script.

So with that in mind, it shouldn't be too hard to bootstrap Laravel's own server implementation and artisan commands into your Lumen app.

If you *really* want to use the `php artisan serve` command rather than something a little more configurable like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com), you can probably just copy Laravel's [server.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php) into the root of your Lumen application, and then register [Laravel's own Serve Command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php) into Lumen.

You'll probably have to change line 42 for your base path, but aside from that, it should be pretty easy to port over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understood what you want to say but I think command `php artisan serve` very helpful for the developers and one thing the Team didn't see about remove that command in release note.

Comment: Apart from giving you the direction you need for putting it back in place yourself, there's not much I can do about that. If you look at the links I sent you, the serve command is really just a very simple wrapper around PHP's built-in server, so you're free to put it back into place on your own. You're also free to [open a pull request](https://github.com/laravel/lumen) or [check the forums](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen). If this answers your question, then please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 94):

Why don't you use PHP's built-in web server which comes out of the box when you install PHP onto your computer?

Just get into the root directory of your Lumen app and type the following, so your project will be served locally.

```
 php -S localhost:8000 -t ./public
```

Note: This PHP built-in web server is intended only for Development environment.

Comment: That is a great idea! I've implemented it in Lumen 5.3. See here: https://gist.github.com/dotnetCarpenter/b0801d4e5e5688de390ed4c1d7342450

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can try changing into the `public` folder of your Lumen application and running `php -S localhost:8080`. This definitely works on OS X - not sure about other platforms. You can also listen on port 80 but you will need to invoke the command with admin rights.

Although PHP's built-in web server was only added at version 5.4, Lumen requires PHP version 5.5.9 or higher, so this solution should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a very lightweight Composer package to add `artisan serve` to your Lumen app https://github.com/mlntn/lumen-artisan-serve

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot simple solution that i had tried.
You can simply use php composer package flipbox/lumen-generator with the following command.

```
composer require flipbox/lumen-generator
```

Then register this package in your app/bootstrap.php file as

```
$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
```

Thats all! You can use php artisan commands to make resources (controller, models) and **

**you can also use the php artisan serve command**