# Lumen Composer cannot detect vendor folder in newly created project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, lumen, laravel-artisan

When creating new Lumen project using:

```
lumen new blogb
```

New directory is being created but **vendor** folders not occurs in newly created folder.

That way when I try

```
php artisan serve
```

I get following errors (because there is no vendor folder):

> Warning:
>   require_once(C:\Users\user\Desktop\blogb\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\blogb\bootstrap\app.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\Users\user\Desktop\blogb\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\blogb\bootstrap\app.php on line 3

EDIT: **laravel new blog** command works ok, and application can be run, but problem happens when *lumen new blog* is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing

```
lumen new blog
```

step in to `blog` directory and do following two things.

1. `cp .env.example .env` to create .env file
2. `composer update` to install and update dependencies. this will create the `vender` directory.

Then once you visit your application in your webserver you'd get something similar to this.

```
Lumen (5.5.0) (Laravel Components 5.5.*)
```

**Note:**

Since [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) is a micro-framework you don't get some steps like `composer update` out-of-the-box like in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). You'd have to do them manually.

And you don't have the `php artisan serve` command either. [Read why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34692894/3918473). use

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

instead or use `Homestead` or `Valet`

Just to Add, you can also use your api doing 
http://localhost:8000/{routename} if you dont want to do 
php -S localhost:8000 -t public

Comment: That exactly fixed my problem. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Required PHP modules should be installed also. And if everything before this step is properly set up (and it should be by default Lumen installation), than just

`composer install`

is enough.