# Lumen: just installed lumen and cannot get resources from public folder

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm trying to start a small project with Lumen, and I have some knowledge on Laravel and Silex. I did the instalation, sent it to my server, and now I'm trying to serve a page, the HTML from the blade file is served, but the css is not.

Code:

.htaccess to redirect all to public:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# direcionar para a raiz do app
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

start.blade.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First page!</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/bulma.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text">Worked!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713635/lumen-not-working-out-of-the-box), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen), [this laracast posts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/fixing-apparent-laravel-package-incompatibility-with-lumen) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/30defc977877e0eba7b2), but the css still 404...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to chmod the folder?

```
cmod 777 public
```

Comment: Yep, problem persisted.